# Upstart | Ubuntu | Nodejs | Can not run multiple exec inside script block

Tags: node.js, upstart

I'm trying to setup a upstart conf for my nodejs app. I have to run 2 script `scrip_1.js` and `script_2.js`. Here the conf

```
start on startup
stop on shutdown

respawn

console log

env PROJ=/project/path

script
    cd $PROJ
    exec node script_1.js 2>&1 >> $PROJ/logs/script_1.log
    exec node script_2.js 2>&1 >> $PROJ/logs/script_2.log
end script
```

The problem is only `script_1.js` running. If I move the `exec node script_2.js...` right before `cd $PROJ` then only `script_2.js` running.

How can I make this upstart conf?

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a separate job for both script 1 and script 2.

Comment: I'm using 2 conf in `/etc/init/` for each command. You mean that?

Comment: Yes, /etc/init/myscript1.conf and /etc/init/myscript2.conf or whatever you want to name them.

Comment: so with upstart conf we can not run 2 commands like my original script?

Comment: No, it can only monitor one process per conf.

Comment: where in the specs is this stated that it can only monitor one process per conf? thanks

Comment: There are job classes, job instances, and job processes. A conf file defines a job class, and when an instance of that class is started various job processes can be started. The job lifecycle detailed in the manpage is a good overview (https://man.voidlinux.org/startup#Job_Lifecycle).  Usually only one process will be running, but post-start and pre-stop are exceptions. The main exec/script stanza will only ever yield a single process that is monitored.